# Adjust horizontal scrollbar location based on parent div height

Tags: css

I'm new to css and not sure how to do this.

I have a parent div that has a fixed height and a child div that has a fixed width with horizontal scroll overflow. The problem is that the child divs horizontal scroll is hidden on the bottom of the div. Is there a way so that the child divs horizontal scroll can be displayed as in the attached picture?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. You have not given us enough details to be able to help you solve your problem. Please refer to this article to see how you can make your post better and receive an answer. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach with jQuery, take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nipunasudha/ddfngj9s/)!

[image]

#### Explanation

This version is desktop & mobile (Touch) compatible. Here, `#scroller` a hidden div with a horizontal scroll-bar to capture the scrolling and adjust the `#inner` div's scroll position.

Maximum horizontal scroll ranges can be different between `#scroller` & `#inner`, so I'm mapping from one range to the other.

#### HTML

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="scroller">
    <div id="expander"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="inner">
    <h1>This is looong text for testing</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

#inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 700px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#scroller {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#expander {
  width: 200%;
  height: 1px;
}

h1 {
  width: 700px;
}
```

#### JQuery

```
$("#outer").on('scroll', function() {
  var oTop = $("#outer").scrollTop();
  $('#scroller').css('top', oTop);
});

$("#scroller").on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollerMax = $(this)[0].scrollWidth - $(this).width();
  var innerMax = $('#inner')[0].scrollWidth - $('#inner').width();
  $('#inner').scrollLeft(mapRange($("#scroller").scrollLeft(), 0, scrollerMax, 0, innerMax))
});

function mapRange(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) {
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. It's weird that things like this is not possible with css. :)

Answer (score 0):

try using position:absolute for the child div. 
if you could post the code i can show you how on your specific example